# c memset pointer array

Tags: c, memset

I have a dynamic allocation of my pointer array with a length of 10.

Now I want to initialize this array with all "1".

But if I print out the array[2] it shows me 0. 
If I print out array[1] it shows me a high number like 4905904374893479. 
Why is this array not set to "1" on all positions?

I don't have much experience with that but I didn't find a solution.

```
uint64_t *array=  malloc((10) * sizeof(uint64_t));
memset(array,1, sizeof(*array));
printf("array[2]: %llu \n", primes[2]);
```

Comment: I think this happens because you try to assign normal integers to an array of 64 bit integers

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. You assign make array of 10 64bit integers. Then you set the first one to 0x01010101010101 (‭72340172838076673‬), the other 9 you don't set at all and their values will be random.

Answer (score 4):

`*array` is a *single* `uint64_t`, not the entire array. That means your `memset` is not setting the entire array, just the first element of it.

And, before you decide to use `sizeof(array)`, be aware that it decays to the *pointer* to that array so will also not be the correct size.

The `memset` function works on bytes rather than wider data types so, unless you want every byte set to the same value, `memset` is not the tool for the job. It works when setting them to `0` simply because that's represented by an all-zero pattern.

Your best bet would be to initialise each explicitly with something like:

```
uint64_t *array=  malloc(10 * sizeof(uint64_t));
// should really check for malloc failure.
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
    array[idx] = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

`memset` fills it with `char`s, so what you get in each 64-bit entry is `0x0101010101010101`.

And BTW, `sizeof(*array)` gives you the size of only a single entry in the array.

You may as well use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    array[i] = 1;
```